# How do I send multiple images using php mail() function from different input fields to an email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments, enctype

I have an HTML form that the user has to fill and upload 6 different files in either, JPG, JPEG, PNG or PDF format and I want when the user uploads the files individually, they'll send as an attachment to the designated email before they get a loan from the company how do I make the PHP code to send all six files as attachments to the designated email? Below is the code

**HTML CODE**

```
<form method="post" action="lib/data_form.php" id="contact-form" class="default-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <select class="form-select" name="company_structure" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Company Structure</option>
                <option value="Sole Proprietor">Sole Proprietor</option>
                <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
                <option value="C-Corp">C-Corp</option>
                <option value="S-Corp">S-Corp</option>
                <option value="LLC">LLC</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="dba_tradename" placeholder="DBA or Tradename (if applicable)" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="year_of_est" placeholder="Year of Establishment" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="business_legal_name" placeholder="Business Legal Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="reg_no" placeholder="Registration Number" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <select class="form-select" name="company_size" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Company Size (including affiliates, if applicable) meets size standard (select one)</option>
                <option value="Less Than 50 Employees">Less Than 50 Employees</option>
                <option value="50 Employees">50 Employees</option>
                <option value="Above 50 Employees">Above 50 Employees</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Business Address (Street, City, State, Zip Code. No P.O. Box addresses allowed)"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="business_status" placeholder="Business Status" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="business_phone" placeholder="Business Phone" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="primary_contact" placeholder="Primary Contact" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="principal_name" placeholder="Principal Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="principal_position" placeholder="Principal Position" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <select class="form-select" name="gender" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option selected>Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Not Disclosed">Not Disclosed</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <!-- <select class="selectpicker" multiple name="company_size" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option>Type of Insurance (more than 1 may be selected)</option>
                <option value="Health Insurance">Health Insurance</option>
                <option value="Life Insurance">Life Insurance</option>
                <option value="Property Insurance">Property Insurance</option>
                <option value="Investment Liability Insurance">Investment Liability Insurance</option>
                <option value="Guarantee Insurance">Guarantee Insurance</option>
                <option value="Not Disclosed">Not Disclosed</option>
            </select> -->
            Type of Insurance
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Health Insurance" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Health Insurance
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Life Insurance" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Life Insurance
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Property Insurance" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Property Insurance
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Investment Liability Insurance" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Investment Liability Insurance
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Guarantee Insurance" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Guarantee Insurance
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" name="insurance_type[]" value="Not Disclosed" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    Not Disclosed
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="certificate" placeholder="Certificate of Incorporation" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="id_card" placeholder="Valid Identification Card" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="executive_summary" placeholder="Executive Summary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="contract" placeholder="Signed Contract with Investor" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="utility" placeholder="Most Recent Utility Bill" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="statement" placeholder="Company Financial Statement" />
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message ..."></textarea>
        </div> -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form group mb-15">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required="">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                    By submitting the form, I confirm that the information is true to the best of my knowledge
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group message-btn">
            <button class="theme-btn-one" type="submit" name="submit-form">
                Submit Now
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP MAIL CODE**

```
<?php
    
if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {
    $company_structure = $_POST['company_structure'];
    $dba_tradename = $_POST['dba_tradename'];
    $year_of_est = $_POST['year_of_est'];
    $business_legal_name = $_POST['business_legal_name'];
    $reg_no = $_POST['reg_no'];
    $company_size = $_POST['company_size'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $business_status = $_POST['business_status'];
    $business_phone = $_POST['business_phone'];
    $primary_contact = $_POST['primary_contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $principal_name = $_POST['principal_name'];
    $principal_position = $_POST['principal_position'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $insurance_type = $_POST['insurance_type'];
    $insur_chk = "";
    foreach ($insurance_type as $insur_chk1) {
        $insur_chk .= $insur_chk1 . ",";
    }

    $subject = "Data Collection Form";

    $to = "info@mywebsite.com";
    $body = "You have received a data application form " .$name. 
    ".\n\n Company Structure: " .$company_structure.
    ".\n\n DBA or Tradename: " .$dba_tradename.
    ".\n\n Year of Establishment: " .$year_of_est.
    ".\n\n Business Legal Name: " .$business_legal_name.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$reg_no.
    ".\n\n Company Size: " .$company_size.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$address.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$business_status.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$business_phone.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$primary_contact.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$email.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$principal_name.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$principal_position.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$gender.
    ".\n\n Registration Number: " .$insur_chk;

    //headers
    $headers = "From: " .$email;
    
    //send
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
     if($send) {
         echo("<script>alert('Thanks for submitting you data, we will get back to you shortly')</script>");
        echo("<script>window.location = '../index.php';</script>");
     }
     else {
         echo "Error in submitting form";
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should start by actually using a mailer library. You tagged this `phpmailer` already - but you are still using PHP's plain old `mail` function.

Comment: Ok, if I want to use a the php mailer library, please could you show me how to implement the image uploads?

Comment: [This is PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Thank you let me check it

Comment: @Synchro But [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) example shows only one input but multiple files and is sending as an array, I need to know how to send it from different input fields like I stated in my code above

Comment: It's not really any different. Look at the single file example in the same folder and repeat the code for other file fields. If you're looking for something that does *exactly* what you want, you're not going to find it, which is why you're writing code.